# How do I add a missing display resolution after upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: display, display-resolution, 17.10, wayland

I'm on Ubuntu 17.10 after upgrading from 17.4. Running an HP ZBook 14 with external HP Z30i screen. Before the upgrade I was using a 2560x1600 display resolution but it's missing after the upgrade.

I tried the standard `xrandr` stuff:

```
$ cvt 2560 1600
$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1600_60.00"  348.50  2560 2760 3032 3504  1600 1603 1609 1658 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND0 "2560x1600_60.00"`
```

with no luck. After running those I'm still not getting the resolution listed in the displays settings UI. Any ideas?

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1200, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 640mm x 400mm
1920x1200     59.88*+    
2560x1600_60.00  59.99
```

I've also tried generating an EDID file as described in https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/99867/how-to-add-a-custom-resolution-to-weyland-fedora-25/:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/akatrevorjay/edid-generator.git
$ cd edid-generator/
$ make
$ ./modeline2edid - <<< 'Modeline "2560x1600_60.00"  348.50  2560 2760 3032 3504  1600 1603 1609 1658 -hsync +vsync'
$ make
$ sudo cp 2560x1600_60.00.bin /usr/lib/firmware/edid/2560x1600_60.00.bin
$ sudo vi /etc/default/grub
 Changed
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
 To
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=edid/2560x1600_60.00.bin"
$ sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Comment: You can try adding that to grub - see https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/99867/how-to-add-a-custom-resolution-to-weyland-fedora-25/ . If it works, I will post it as an answer pulling from askfedora and the arch wiki.

Comment: No luck with that. I've also tried a similar approach earlier, using `get-edid`

Comment: Thank you. Can you please run `sudo update-grub` and reboot. When you reboot make sure that modified default line is in effect. Not sure if it matters, but do you have secure boot enabled ? Try disabling secure boot and boot without the splash (to see boot messages) or check your boot log to see if there is any error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the HDMI male to female adapter I was using was the problem. I switched to another version from the same company and now all the resolutions are showing as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I got problems using the default values for newmode provided by cvt.
Using `xrandr --props | edid-decode` output, I came up with the following newmode, that finally got me to 2560x1600 resolution:

```
$ xrandr --newmode "2560x1600"  268.50  2560 2608 2640 2720  1600 1603 1609 1646 +hsync -vsync
```

When I was trying with the suggested newmode, I received error message: `xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed`.